# Customizing a Winforms Settings Page

Tags: c#, winforms, customization, settings.settings

I've got a [settings page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28APPLICATIONSETTINGSOVERVIEW%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29&rd=true) built up in C# and I'd like to customize it in 2 ways.

1. I'd like the different settings to be sorted in a particular order that is not alphabetic
2. I'd like to enable/disable the editing of certain settings based off of the values of other settings.

Is it possible to do this with a settings page or do I need to design a custom control?

Thanks!

Comment: C# is not necessarily related to a specific application building suite. Are you using Winforms? Unity3D? Your question is not C#-specific.

Comment: The page you referenced refers to the Visual Studio Project properties page, specifically, the "Settings" tab on that page. Are you looking to customize the Visual Studio view, or have you done something else inside your application? Providing a more accurate link (or a picture of the actual dialog box you're using) would help.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion - I'm still trying to sort out the mechanics of this.  I believe the specific winform is a PropertyGrid and these pull in the items in the .settings file.  I'm trying to change the appearance of the property grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the PropertyGrid control you can read up on how to customise it [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3397/Bending-the-NET-PropertyGrid-to-Your-Will) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163816.aspx).

In order to display properties some of the time you can implement the ICustomTypeDescriptor interface by doing this you will be able to control the order and the list of properties to be edited dynamically.

Comment: Glad I could help (don't forget to accept this answer if you think it is complete)